# Can Cranelift or LLVM IRs be used to develop a simple OS from scratch?

Tags: operating-system, llvm, llvm-ir, instruction-set

I am curious if I can develop my own programming language to output Cranelift or LLVM IRs, then use it to make a simple OS from scratch?

Specifically, do the instruction sets of Cranelift/LLVM IRs contain OS-level IO instructions?

Thank you.

Comment: LLVM-IR must allow inline-asm, since clang can compile C sources that use inline asm, and I think that works even if you compile through a temporary file with LLVM-IR text.  I don't know whether there are other ways to represent special instructions like x86 `invlpg` in LLVM-IR; I'd guess not.

Comment: Hi @PeterCordes. I have posted another question related to this one if you would like to pass by: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74842486/can-io-of-different-cpu-architectures-be-abstracted-with-an-instruction-set-for